# React JS // Editing style of one component from another component

Tags: reactjs

My goal is to create a basic app that allows me to change the style of one component with an action from another component.

Lets assume I have a `<Btn/>` component and a `<Box/>` component and when the button is clicked, I want to change the background color of the box. `<Btn/>` and `<Box/>` have the common ancestor of `<App/>` but are both at different levels in the component tree.

*Btn.js*

```
import React from 'react'

function Btn() {

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    //...
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>
      Click me
    </button>
  );
}

export default Btn
```

*Box.js*

```
import React from 'react'

function Box() {
  return (
    <h1>
       Hello World!
    </h1>
  );
}

export default Box
```

I do not want to use prop drilling (with style setting/getting functionality in the `<App/>` component) to achieve this. I have also deliberately left out component styling as I am open to whichever styling option is best to solve this problem.

What would be the best way to go about this? (I'm open to using Context, Redux or another library if it is appropriate.)

Comment: Personally I would go with redux/context and styled-components. You can pass `props` to styled-components and do something like `color: ${props => props.color}`, which would let you dynamically assign the color.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of doing this is with Context, as you're using function components not classes the documentation you'll need is `useContext` https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext. You still have to define the prop and "setter" function at the app level or at a component called at the app level, but with context you don't have to pass the props all the way down.

To take their example and adapt it to your use case would go something like this. (Working sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-answer-7hryk)

```js
const themes = {
  light: {
    foreground: "#000000",
    background: "#eeeeee"
  },
  dark: {
    foreground: "#ffffff",
    background: "#222222"
  }
};

const ThemeContext = React.createContext(themes.light);

function App() {
  const [stateTheme, setTheme] = useState('light');
  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme: themes[stateTheme], setTheme: setStateTheme }}>
      <Toolbar />
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
}

function Toolbar(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <ToggleButtons />
      <ThemedButton />
    </div>
  );
}

function ToggleButtons() {
  const { setTheme } = useContext(ThemeContext);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setTheme('light')}>Light Theme</button>
      <button onClick={() => setTheme('dark')}>Dark Theme</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function ThemedButton() {
  const { theme } = useContext(ThemeContext);

  return (
    <button style={{ background: theme.background, color: theme.foreground }}>
      I am styled by theme context!
    </button>
  );
}
```